# I want to use my location data collected by openpaths. Are there any example programs using openpaths apis?

Tags: php, api, location

I would like to write my own web app using PHP to access my location data collected using openpaths. Openpaths provides API's to access the location data but i am a noob to web programming. I am not able to kickstart my application to access the location data. Are there any example programs using [**openpaths**](https://openpaths.cc/) APIs ?